# Ruby RSpec doesn't run tests

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, rake

My rakefile selenium task doesn't run any tests and gives no error.
My files:

```
Rakefile

desc 'Selenium test'
task :selenium => [:init] do

    RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new() do |t|
        t.pattern = 'test/selenium/*.rb'
        t.verbose = true
    end
    print 'wtf'
end
```

test/selenium/test1.rb:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "rspec"
include RSpec::Expectations
describe "Test" do

  before(:each) do
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for "ie"
    @base_url = "my site"   
    @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 10
    @verification_errors = []
    @driver.get(@base_url)
  end

  after(:each) do
    @driver.quit
    @verification_errors.should == []
  end

  it "test_" do
    #verify { element_present?(:link, "Edit campaign").should be_true }
    verify { element_present?(:link, "Campaign list").should be_true }
    (@driver.find_element(:link, "Campaign list").text).should == "Campaign list"
  end

  def element_present?(how, what)
```

Result:

```
wtf
```

test is not running, no error is shown

Answer (score 1):

Rename:

```
test/selenium/test1.rb
```

to:

```
test/selenium/test1_spec.rb
```